# Sending SMTP when deployed

Tags: c#

locally my smtp code works perfectly, when I deploy onto plesk - godaddy hosting, it seems to not work anymore. May I get some assistance as to why it would stop when it's deployed?

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage())
{
    const string smtp = "smtp.gmail.com";
    const int port = 587;

    var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx");


    mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = message.ToString();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try
    {
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp, port))
        {
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }

    }

    finally
    {
        //dispose the client
        mail.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to catch the exception and write it to log so that you can know what exception is happening .

Comment: Don't dispose it. That's not necessary, the using block takes care of that for you.